# Change location of Application Insights?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

Would it be possible to change the location of my Application Insights service without having to delete and recreate it? Now that it is in RTM, new regions (such as North Europe) are now supported.

Comment: I am inclined to say no but I couldn't find any information to back it up. It may not hurt asking this question here as well: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/general-availability-of-azure-application-insights/.

Comment: I'm with Gaurav on this one

Comment: Good point. Will report back. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to move the apps around the new region, unfortunately. Microsoft can manually move them for you if you contact the support, but this will mean you will lose the history.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft is currently working on a new capability that will allow customers to move Azure resources from one region to another:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/923992-cross-region-move-for-azure-resources/suggestions/19224478-change-geographical-region-for-a-given-resource

[UPDATE] In September 2020 Microsoft implemented Azure Resource Mover which can move resources from one region to another but unfortunately it seems the Application Insights is not supported so far: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/resource-mover/overview