# Backup and Import Azure Application Insight entries

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I am working on a requirement currently where-in I have to change the region for App Insight resource. Going by the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40655870/change-location-of-application-insights), its not possible to do it directly and contacting support would mean losing history. The strategy my company is going for is to create a new App insight resource and delete the old app insight project after 90 days as data retention for App insight is just 90 days.

The concern I have with this approach is managing 2 accounts and I want to work on an alternative strategy by using a backup and import strategy with Application Insight. With this background, I have a few questions:

1. Is there a backup and import feature for App Insights. An export can be taken using the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/export-telemetry) but I have not been able to find any documentation for importing App Insights. Do App Insights have an import feature?
2. What is the easiest way of re-creating dashboard and reporting in the new App Insight resource? Will this be taken care of if we ask Azure Support for changing the region as per [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40655870/change-location-of-application-insights)
3. Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: A simple way I can think of is that: you can keep the data in the old app insights(and don't remove the old app insight), then in the new app insights, you can cross-query data from the old / new app insights.

Comment: @IvanYang - Thanks for the response. Considering the fact that data retention is 90 days, your idea is perfect but the problem is that I will have to still manually create charts and graphs for the new app insights resource.

Comment: There is no import feature in app insights. I will take a look if we can find a easy way to re-create dashboard.

Comment: Thanks Again @IvanYang. What are your thoughts in replicating charts and graphs? I tried a dirty way of downloading JSON from the old dashboard and updating the JSON with properties of new App Insights resource and then uploading the modified JSON

Answer (score 1):

If you have metric charts (charts pinned from metrics blade) only on your dashboard, you can download the json of dashboard and update the resource names to new instance and upload them back with a new name.