# How to migrate Application Insights from one region to another?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have one Application Insights azure resource located in East US region, whereas its coresponding App Service resided in North Central US region. The App Service links to Application Insights via InstrumentationKey.
I want to make them to the same region to improve network efficiency. It seems impossible to change the resource region yet. My idea is to create a new Application Insights in North Central US region, then migrate the data from the old one to the new one. 
Is it possible? If yes, how to do? Thanks!

Comment: Similar question: [Change location of Application Insights?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40655870/change-location-of-application-insights?rq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of now, it's impossible to do that, but Microsoft is working on [move Azure resources from one region to another](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/923992-cross-region-move-for-azure-resources/suggestions/19224478-change-geographical-region-for-a-given-resource). If this feature is done, you can just move app insights to another region directly.

And you should know that even the `application insights` and the `app service` are in different regions, the `ingest endpoints of application insights` are globally distributed, and telemetry is always sent to the nearest available `ingest point`. So the performance is not impacted. You can see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Home/issues/299).

Comment: Unfortunately both of those urls are now broken.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, No , currently it is not possible.  Microsoft team can manually move them for you if you contact the support, but i dont think you will retain the history of the insights data